# Is $D=\hom_K(\cdot, K)$ exact?

Tags: representation-theory

Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field. On page 31 of the book Elements of representation theory of associative algebras, volume 1, from Theorem 5.13 (a) we see that $D=\hom_K(\cdot, K)$ is exact. But we know that $\hom$ is left exact and not necessarily exact. I am confused about this. Is it because $D=\hom_K(\cdot, K)$ but not $\hom_A(\cdot, A)$, where $A$ is a $K$-algebra. Thank you very much.

[image]

Comment: $K$ is obviously injective as $K$-module. Actually $\mathrm{Hom}_K(-,V)$ is exact for *any* $K$-module $V$, because $K$ is a field, so a semisimple ring.

Comment: @egreg Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Comment: @JulianKuelshammer Done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $K$ is a field, it's in particular semisimple and every $K$-module is injective, which amounts to say that
$$
\operatorname{Hom}_K(-,V)
$$
is exact for any $K$-module $V$.

A doubt could arise because the functor $D=\operatorname{Hom}_K(-,K)$ is considered as $D\colon\operatorname{mod} A\to\operatorname{mod}A^{\mathrm{op}}$, but this is irrelevant; what is needed is only that, when $M\to N$ is monic in $\operatorname{mod}A$, the morphism
$$
\operatorname{Hom}_K(N,K)\to\operatorname{Hom}_K(M,K)
$$
is epic, which is true.